# upload form for SimpleHTTPServerWithUpload.py

Tags: python, html

I am trying to write an html form for file upload for use with SimpleHTTPServerWithUpload.py.
This is what I have so far:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="upload">file:</label>
   <input type="file" id="upload"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

File upload with curl works fine, but I can't find out how to do it via a web page.
What do I need to supply for action? Is there anything else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It works with the name tag for the file input:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="upload">file:</label>
   <input name="file" type="file" id="upload"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```